# Does CGBitmapContextCreate() have a size limit?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-graphics

I want to make an extremely large bitmap (250,000 pixels on each side, to be eventually written out as BigTIFF). I don't see a memory size or dimensional limit anywhere in the docs, can Core Graphics handle it?

Comment: You will need caching somehow, as this will take up about 190GB of ram if you try to load it all at once.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a memory limit for the data type but there is a memory limit on computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CG is not designed for that kind of workload.

(I'd be surprised if you found any general-purpose graphics framework that is, frankly. If you're pushing images that big, you're going to have to write your own code to get anything done in a reasonable amount of time.)

In my experience, images started to fail once dimensions got over 32767 or so. Not in any organized way, just crashes and hard-to-repro failures; certain parts of the API would work, others wouldn't. Things may be better in 64-bit but I wouldn't count on it.